# Can the singular values be plotted?

Tags: statistics, matlab, svd

I have a set of 3 x 3 co-variance matrices that I need to plot.

Using singular value decomposition (svd) in Matlab I managed to obtains a vector of singular values for each matrix as stated [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html).

I did plot the resulting singular vector on a 3D plot and got a spread of points which I could explain according to my experiment.

My question is whether this type of plotting is permitted and correct? If not how can I plot a set of co-variance matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wrote in the comment to my other attempt at an answer that you want to visualize covariance matrices to see whether they are different, I'd recommend you simply plot the matrix entries coded by color. The plotting can be done by `pcolor`, but for the comparison it is important to have a common colorscale.

Assuming you have `nm` matrices of size `nv` x `nv` stored as a three-dimensional array `c` of dimension  `nv` x `nv` x `nm`:

```
figure
minc = min(c(:));
maxc = max(c(:));
for i = 1 : nm
    subplot(3, 4, i)     % adjust such that the number of subplots is >= nm
    C = c(:, :, i);
    C(nv + 1, nv + 1) = 0;
    pcolor(0.5 + (0 : nv), 0.5 + (0 : nv), double(C))
    axis equal tight
    caxis([-minc, maxc])
end
```

The result might look for example like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"permitted and correct" depends on how you want to interpret the plot.

I'd prefer to plot the L2-normalized singular vectors multiplied by the corresponding singular values, or equivalently, the L2-normalized eigenvectors multiplied by the square roots of eigenvalues. The reason is that these vectors correspond to the uncorrelated variance components (aka principal components) of the three correlated variables characterized by the given covariance matrix. Moreover, if the variables are jointly normally distributed, the ellipsoid spanned by these three vectors corresponds to the 1$\sigma$-surface of that multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: So you answer means that if I get the L2 norm of each covariance matrix and multiply it by its corresponding singular value I should get a better plot?

Comment: Not the norm, but the *L2-normalized* singular vector (unless they already are, not sure with `svd`). Better if you are interested in the kind of interpretation of your plot that I described – it really depends on what you want to use the plot for.

Comment: I want to see where each co-variance matrix is placed in the 3D space so I can make a decision on the method I have developed.

Comment: Just read up: `U` and `V` are unitary, so the vectors which make them up are normalized.

Comment: Ok, but how exactly would you use such a plot to make that decision? What are the criteria you want to apply?

Comment: I want to see the set covarainace matrices I have do not represent the same matrix and are unique. I though plotting is the best way since I'm not a maths person

Comment: In that case I'd just plot the matrix entries. See my new answer.